# Trying to list Devpay S3 buckets - getting "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error

Tags: php, amazon-s3

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to list Devpay S3 buckets.

**References I'm using:**
1. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTServiceGET.html
2. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonDevPay/latest/DevPayDeveloperGuide/QuickReferenceS3Products.html
3. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonDevPay/2007-12-01/DevPayDeveloperGuide/DesktopAWSCalls.html

**How I'm doing it:**
A simple REST GET request using the PHP libcURL library:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Date: $date
X-Amz-Date: $date
X-Amz-Security-Token: $userToken, $productToken
Authorization: $signatureValue
```

where

```
$date // = timestamp at the time of request

$signatureValue //= Authorization: AWS $signature

$signature //= $userAccessKey:$signatureString

$signatureString //=base64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 of $stringToSign with $userSecretKey

$stringToSign //= utf8 encoded string:
```

this string -

```
GET\n
""\n
""\n
$date\n
$canonicalized_AMZ_Headers\n
/
```

I'm using `curl_exec()` to execute the GET request.

**Error that I'm getting:**

> "SignatureDoesNotMatch"
>   "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method"

**Thanks!**
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the returned error message from S3 will be a StringToSign element (use View Source to see it more clearly). Compare this carefully with the string you are appending together to sign the request — they must be **exactly** the same.

Comment: The string to sign returned by S3 didn't have the `$date` in it ... so I removed it. Comparing my `$stringToSign` and the StringToSign returned by Amazon - both seem to be the same; unfortunately so does the error :(

Comment: Signed S3 URLs should __always__ include the expire time. The expire time also needs to set as a query parameter. See the [Authentication page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) for the exact details. I'm not a PHP guy (or a Devpay person either!), but AWS does ship a [PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) that should take care of most of the muck. HTH.

Comment: Thanks Uriah - i'm not using signed URLs. I was able to resolve this issue by excluding the x-amz-date header and inluding a regular `"Date:..."` header instead. Also the two security tokens needed to be separately listed when not in a canonicalized form.

p.s. the php sdk unfortunately does not work with devpay s3 buckets :( - thanks for all your input